# Existence of $\delta_p(A)=\int_Ah \space d \lambda$

Tags: integration, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

We are looking at the measure space $(\mathbb{R}^d, \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R}^d),\delta_p)$, for all $A\subset \mathbb{R}^d$:

$\delta_p(A):=\begin{cases}
1, & \text{if } p \in A \\
0, & \text{otherwise} 
\end{cases}$.

Let $\lambda$ be the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}^d$. Does an integratable function $h: \mathbb{R}^d \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ exist such that for $A \subset \mathbb{R}^d: \delta_p(A)=\int_Ah \space d  \lambda$?

Comment: Are you familiar with absolutely continuous measures?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $A = \{ x | x \neq 0, h(x) \ge 0 \}$, then $\int_A h d \lambda = 0$ and so $h = 0$ ae. $[\lambda]$ and similarly
on $B = \{ x | x \neq 0, h(x) \le 0 \}$. In particular, $h = 0$ ae. $[\lambda]$ and so $\int_A h  d \lambda =0 $ for all measurable $A$.